# I need to output the desired value to a variable and then check by condition C#

Tags: c#, methods, task, massive

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

namespace TimeTress
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var timelineCSV = GetListOfStringsFromTextFile("../../../../timeline.csv");
            var peopleCSV = GetListOfStringsFromTextFile("../../../../people.csv");

            var timeline = ReadData(timelineCSV);
            var people = ReadData(peopleCSV);

            //OutputString(timelineCSV);
            //OutputString(peopleCSV);

            //Console.WriteLine(DeltaMinAndMaxDate(timeline));
            //Console.WriteLine(GetMinAndMaxDate(timeline));

            Console.WriteLine(NamePeoples(people));
        }

        static (string,int) NamePeoples(string[][] people)
        {
            string names = null;
            int years = 0;

            foreach (var elements in people)
            {
                DateTime bitrthdayElement = ParseDate(elements[2]);
                var yearBirthday = bitrthdayElement.Year;
                var namePeople = elements[1];
                names = namePeople;
                years = yearBirthday;
                return (names, years);
            }

            return ("no",0);
        }

        static (int, int, int) DeltaMinAndMaxDate(string[][] timeline)
        {
            (DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate) = GetMinAndMaxDate(timeline);
            return (maxDate.Year - minDate.Year,
                maxDate.Month - minDate.Month,
                maxDate.Day - minDate.Day);
        }

        static (DateTime, DateTime) GetMinAndMaxDate(string[][] timeline)
        {
            DateTime minDate = DateTime.MaxValue, maxDate = DateTime.MinValue;

            foreach (var timeEvent in timeline)
            {
                DateTime date = ParseDate(timeEvent[0]);

                if (date < minDate) minDate = date;
                if (date > maxDate) maxDate = date;
            }

            return (minDate, maxDate);
        }

        static string[] GetListOfStringsFromTextFile(string filePath)
        {
            string[] stringArray;

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                stringArray = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            }
            else
            {
                stringArray = new string[0];
            }

            return stringArray;
        }

        static void OutputString(string[] getString)
        {
            foreach (var lines in getString)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lines);
            }
        }

        static string[][] ReadData(string[] array)
        {
            string[][] splitData = new string[array.Length][];

            for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                var line = array[i];
                string[] parts = line.Split(";");
                splitData[i] = parts;
            }

            return splitData;
        }

        static DateTime ParseDate(string value)
        {
            DateTime date;

            if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyy-mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                {
                    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyy-mm-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("WRONG FORMAT");
                    }
                }
            }

            return date;
        }
    }
}
```

Method `NamePeoples` output only first result. But I need to make the code display all values recorded in the `people.csv` file, they are stored in the format {count; name; date}, this method should save them all to a variable, there are currently 4 lines, then this method should either be different, I don't understand how to implement this, from the data that we thought we could select the names of people who were born in a leap year.

Check can be done by calling this function:

```
DateTime.IsLeapYear(yearBirthday)
```

Comment: Actually NamePeoples returns the first line, not the last one. If you single stepped this in a debugger you'd find out exactly why (a loop with an unconditional return is not a loop at all)..

Comment: but i can't fixed it and create correct method

Comment: Do you know how to use the Visual Studio debugger?

Comment: Yes, i'am sorry, return first result, but i know how he can return last result, but i don't know how i can get all values in massive or strong, or i don't know

Comment: Put the cursor on the first line of NamePeoples method, press F9 so it goes red, press F5, press F10 to advance the yellow bar step by step, *watch* what the code does. Honestly, as soon as you watch it in slow motion you'll see what the problem is

Comment: *this method should save them all to a variable* - they are already saved to a variable, by the way. [Eric Lippert's words on debugging small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/) would be a worthwhile read

Comment: Okey, he take string[4][] problem in this?

Comment: Please, single step it in the debugger and you'll see exactly why. I've given you the instructions above (F9, F5, F10 a few times), there are about 10 keypresses required to get to the point where you're inside the loop and hit the return statement that's causing your problem, *but I want you to see it so you learn the process*. If you knew the basic techniques for debugging this, it would save you a bunch of time because you wouldn't have even needed to type out this long question-the most important thing I hope you'll learn from this question is that solving things like this yourself is easy

Comment: i don't understand this problem

Comment: Have you followed the steps I gave? Did you put the cursor on the first line of NamePeoples? Did you press F9? Did the line go red? Did you press F5? Did you see a yellow bar? Did you press F10 repeatedly and watch the code execute slowly, line by line?

Comment: Yes, string by string, and one's what i knowed what he take string[4][] but what that denote i don't no and how fix it

Comment: Your complaint is that you have 4 people but you only manage to print one. Step it and see why you only print one; you print the return value of NamePeoples. NamePeoples only ever returns one person. The foreach loop in NamePeoples doesn't loop, and even if it did, it couldn't possibly return 4 people because the NamePeople method can only return one person